# Android : Fragment doesn't open on clicking on Notification

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, notifications, android-notifications

I have same problem as many but doesn't seems to find solution by their answers, so I have to write my own..

I have a notification from which I would like to open a fragment by clicking on it but it doesn't open WHY?

here is my code

```
 public void showStatusNotification() {

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setAction("OpenStatusFragment");

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.dc_feedback)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("Order Id DC256649")
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setContentText("Your Order has been cancelled as per your request");


    //mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId2, mBuilder.build());
    Log.v("notification","Notification");
}
```

I am defining this code in MainActivity.java only

In `onCreate` method I am opening fragment like

```
final android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(getIntent().getAction().equals("OpenNotificationFragment")) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_main_container, new NotificationFragment()).addToBackStack(PastOrderFragment.TAG)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
    else {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_main_container, new OrderStatusFragment()).addToBackStack(PastOrderFragment.TAG)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
```

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue when the app is open in the background and you click the notification, when the app is closed and not in the background and you click the notification, or both?

Comment: I am able to open Activity now but unable to open Fragment